# SQL: How to get change in value between two adjacent rows in a time series?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `NEW_YORK_TEMPERATURES` like:

Note: Spacing added to show different locations and dates

```
datetime,           location, min_temp, max_temp

2018-01-01 12:00:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5
2018-01-01 12:10:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5
2018-01-01 12:20:00,  seneca,     76.2,     76.6
2018-01-01 12:30:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.6
2018-01-01 12:40:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5

2018-01-02 12:00:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3
2018-01-02 12:10:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3
2018-01-02 12:20:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3
2018-01-02 12:30:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3
2018-01-02 12:40:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3

2018-01-01 12:00:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5
2018-01-01 12:10:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5
2018-01-01 12:20:00, conesus,     66.2,     66.6
2018-01-01 12:30:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.6
2018-01-01 12:40:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5

2018-01-02 12:00:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.7
2018-01-02 12:10:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.8
2018-01-02 12:20:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9
2018-01-02 12:30:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9
2018-01-02 12:40:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9   

2018-01-01 12:00:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5
2018-01-01 12:10:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5
2018-01-01 12:20:00, ontario,     63.2,     63.6
2018-01-01 12:30:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.6
2018-01-01 12:40:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5

2018-01-02 12:00:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8
2018-01-02 12:10:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8    
2018-01-02 12:20:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8
2018-01-02 12:30:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.7
2018-01-02 12:40:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.7
```

I need a way to get the difference in the change in the range between two consecutive timestamps. 
The first step is to create a spread column by doing:

```
select 
    datetime, 
    location, 
    min_temp, 
    max_temp, 
    max_temp - min_temp as range 
from NEW_YORK_TEMPERATURES 
order by datetime
```

To get a table like:

```
datetime,           location, min_temp, max_temp, range

2018-01-01 12:00:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:10:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:20:00,  seneca,     76.2,     76.6,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:30:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.6,   0.5
2018-01-01 12:40:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5,   0.4

2018-01-02 12:00:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7
2018-01-02 12:10:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7
2018-01-02 12:20:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7
2018-01-02 12:30:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7
2018-01-02 12:40:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7

2018-01-01 12:00:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:10:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:20:00, conesus,     66.2,     66.6,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:30:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.6,   0.5
2018-01-01 12:40:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5,   0.4

2018-01-02 12:00:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.7,   0.3
2018-01-02 12:10:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.8,   0.4
2018-01-02 12:20:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9,   0.5
2018-01-02 12:30:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9,   0.5
2018-01-02 12:40:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9,   0.5

2018-01-01 12:00:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:10:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:20:00, ontario,     63.2,     63.6,   0.4
2018-01-01 12:30:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.6,   0.5
2018-01-01 12:40:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5,   0.4

2018-01-02 12:00:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8,   0.5
2018-01-02 12:10:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8,   0.5   
2018-01-02 12:20:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8,   0.5
2018-01-02 12:30:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.7,   0.4
2018-01-02 12:40:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.7,   0.4
```

But how can I get the changes in the range between adjacent bars in the same location so that my result looks like:

```
datetime,           location, min_temp, max_temp, range, change_in_range

2018-01-01 12:00:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5,   0.4              nan
2018-01-01 12:10:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5,   0.4              0.0
2018-01-01 12:20:00,  seneca,     76.2,     76.6,   0.4              0.0
2018-01-01 12:30:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.6,   0.5              0.1
2018-01-01 12:40:00,  seneca,     76.1,     76.5,   0.4             -0.1

2018-01-02 12:00:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7              0.0
2018-01-02 12:10:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7              0.0
2018-01-02 12:20:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7              0.0
2018-01-02 12:30:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7              0.0
2018-01-02 12:40:00,  seneca,     76.6,     77.3,   0.7              0.0

2018-01-01 12:00:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5,   0.4              nan
2018-01-01 12:10:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5,   0.4              0.0
2018-01-01 12:20:00, conesus,     66.2,     66.6,   0.4              0.0
2018-01-01 12:30:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.6,   0.5              0.1
2018-01-01 12:40:00, conesus,     66.1,     66.5,   0.4              0.0

2018-01-02 12:00:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.7,   0.3             -0.1
2018-01-02 12:10:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.8,   0.4              0.1
2018-01-02 12:20:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9,   0.5              0.1
2018-01-02 12:30:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9,   0.5              0.0
2018-01-02 12:40:00, conesus,     66.4,     66.9,   0.5              0.0

2018-01-01 12:00:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5,   0.4              nan
2018-01-01 12:10:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5,   0.4              0.0
2018-01-01 12:20:00, ontario,     63.2,     63.6,   0.4              0.0
2018-01-01 12:30:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.6,   0.5              0.1
2018-01-01 12:40:00, ontario,     63.1,     63.5,   0.4             -0.1

2018-01-02 12:00:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8,   0.5              0.1
2018-01-02 12:10:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8,   0.5              0.0
2018-01-02 12:20:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.8,   0.5              0.0
2018-01-02 12:30:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.7,   0.4             -0.1
2018-01-02 12:40:00, ontario,     63.3,     63.7,   0.4              0.0
```

Comment: The `0` for "2018-01-02 12:00:00/seneca" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `LAG`:

```
SELECT 
    datetime,
    location,
    min_temp,
    max_temp,
    max_temp - min_temp AS range,
    (max_temp - min_temp) - LAG(max_temp - min_temp) OVER
        (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY datetime) change_in_range
FROM NEW_YORK_TEMPERATURES 
ORDER BY
    location, datetime;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You would use `lag()` with a lateral join:

```
select t.*, v.range,
       (range - lag(range) over (partition by location order by datetime)) as change_in_range
from NEW_YORK_TEMPERATURES t cross join lateral
     (values (max_temp - min_temp)) v(range)
order by location, datetime;
```

Note:  This will represent the first values for each location as `NULL` rather than `nan`.

Also, for your desired output, you want `order by location, datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you want to partition the "range diff" by both the date (truncated from the `datetime` field) **and** location, you'll need to add the truncated date to your `LAG` function. Using a CTE, you get something like this:

```
    WITH temps_with_ranges AS
    (
        SELECT *, 
            date_trunc('day', datetime) AS dt, 
            max_temp - min_temp AS "range"
        FROM NEW_YORK_TEMPERATURES
    )
SELECT * , "range" - LAG("range") OVER (PARTITION BY location, dt ORDER BY datetime)
FROM temps_with_ranges
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from what I gave yesterday?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yours didn't partition by location and date. Also, I think the CTE makes things a bit cleaner.

Comment: Look closely at the expected range diff in the original question.  There is no partition by date, only by location.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I agree that the expected results don't explicitly indicate he wanted to partition by date, but OP also had a visual separation between date groups as well as location groups. So I would argue that there's value in at least offering that as an option. Also, as Gordon Linoff noted, the expected results aren't consistent anyways.